# How to run ansible inventory script with python3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm running a docker container with alpine.And running ansible [script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#inventory-script-example-aws-ec2) for getting dynamic inventory from AWS and it works great with python2. But I'm changing it to python3 and this is causing me issues. Getting warnings and unable to parse it

In python2 I was able to run the python script this way ./ec2.py

Now with python3, I'm getting this error: `env: can't execute 'python': No such file or directory`

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse ci/ec2.py with script
 plugin: Inventory script (ci/ec2.py) had an execution
 error: env: can't execute 'python': No such file or directory
 [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse ci/ec2.py with ini plugin:
 ci/ec2.py:3: Error parsing host definition ''''': No
 closing quotation
 [WARNING]: Unable to parse ci/ec2.py as an inventory
 source
 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
 the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

**Python3**

```
apk --update --no-cache add python3 py3-setuptools
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install awscli ansible boto
chmod 755 ec2.py
ansible-playbook provisioning/ec2New.yml  -i ec2.py --private-key ssh-key.pem -e "type_inventory=${TYPE_INVENTORY}
```

**ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
stdout_callback = yaml
ansible_python_interpreter = /usr/bin/python3
```

My old configuration with **python 2**

```
apk --update --no-cache add python py-pip
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install awscli ansible botocore boto
chmod 755 ec2.py
ansible-playbook provisioning/ec2New.yml  -i ec2.py --private-key ssh-key.pem -e "type_inventory=${TYPE_INVENTORY}
```

**old ansible.cfg**

```
defaults
host_key_checking = False
stdout_callback = yaml
```

Comment: The problem is with the shebang line of the python script. Can you post the first line of your `ec2.py` file?

Comment: Or side step that discussion entirely and just make a wrapper: `echo 'exec python3 ec2.py "$@"' > ec2.sh; chmod 755 ec2.sh; ansible-inventory -i ./ec2.sh --list`

Comment: @franklinsijo this first line is this way: #!/usr/bin/env python
Should I replace the value

Comment: Yes, easy fix -- Change python to python3.

Comment: If I replace it 
getting this: /usr/bin/python3: can't open file 'python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Are you referencing python anywhere else in your script?

Comment: Just what I had in the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue described above, if you change the first line in your `ec2.py` file to be:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Then it should parse and work as expected.

---

I noticed your comment and it seems `python3` was replaced wrong in the [shebang](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/testing/sanity/shebang.html).

> If I replace it getting this: /usr/bin/python3: can't open file 'python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory –
> Diego
> Apr 10, 2020 at 3:43

So, if you follow the solution above it "should" work.